# Can I only use normal mode and insert mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

I don't need other mode except this two, so I don't want to switch to `Visual Mode` automatically when I highlight some text, or a variety of other automatic mode switching.

Just start and stay in `Insert Mode`, switch to `Normal Mode` only when I press `<Esc>`, after some action, press `i/a/I/A...` to go back to `Insert Mode`.

Other features I will use other tools to achieve.

Thanks for help.

---

**Edit:**

This should be what I actually want, it seems I asked a wrong question.
[VSCodeVim issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1871)

Comment: Why would you? All of modes in vim are powerful

Answer (score 6):

There's only a limited set of commands that changes modes. You can neutralize them, e.g.:

```
" No visual mode.
:nnoremap v <Nop>
:nnoremap V <Nop>
:nnoremap <C-v> <Nop>

" No command-line mode.
:nnoremap : <Nop>
...
```

And additionally `:set mouse=`, as mentioned in @windyjonas answer.

#### But... why?

I don't understand the motivation for this. For inexperienced users, a non-modal editor (or `:help easy` mode) would be much better than forcing the steep learning curve of Vim onto them. Other users probably don't like the limitations you force on them.

If this is for security (e.g. to avoid breaking out of normal editing by `:source`ing plugins, `:call system()`, etc.), it will be hard to find and close all loopholes. There are better ways to address this (see `sudoedit`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.


Because I use Vim in VSCode by install the Vim plug-in. Those functions, multi-line select/edit, edit the same words at the same time, search for words, etc. VSCode can do well.


Furthermore, I wrote a tool to easily move the caret and select the text in `Insert Mode`, I am used to use it.
[Capslock+](http://cjkis.me/capslock+) (Only chinese so far, sorry about that)


So I only need a part of the function from Vim, switching the mode frequently and automatically to move the caret or select the text seems to me as a burden.

**Can't wrap here?!**

Answer (score 5):

Add `set mouse-=a` to your ~/.vimrc file.